# Smart way to extend matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

For example I have 2x2 matrix, now i have to increase its left and right side to 1 column each, then top and bottom side to 1 row each, now I will have a 4x4 matrix with the old matrix is located in the center of the new one. Is there any way to do it fast rather than create new one and transfer values from old to new one?

 Thank you very much

Comment: Some ways to do this with the Image Processing Toolbox are discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/q/8287289/462117

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will always have to allocate new memory for the new array, no matter what you do.

Also, if your matrix is only 2x2, the speed of any approach is good enough. Or do you want to handle larger matrices as well? Then, consider the following tests of two methods you can use:

```
A = rand(5000);

% explicitly add zero vectors on all sides of A
tic;
B = [zeros(1, size(A,1)+2);
    zeros(size(A, 2),1) A zeros(size(A, 2),1);
    zeros(1, size(A,1)+2)];
toc

Elapsed time is 0.204940 seconds.

% create the output array and assign the A array to correct sub-matrix
tic
B = zeros(size(A)+2);
B(2:end-1,2:end-1) = A;
toc

Elapsed time is 0.102501 seconds.
```

Comment: can you please explain this line of code for me ? "B(2:end-1,2:end-1) = A;"

Comment: @Aptos Read about [matrix indexing in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.se/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html;jsessionid=92d1cab9d60af8757dc730078854). This command assigns to `B` starting from index 2 and ending at end-1 in both dimensions. Since the dimensions of B are that of A + 2, you assign to a sub-matrix of correct size (i.e., size(A))

Answer (score 2):

Another option is

```
B = padarray(A,[1,1],'both');
```

For speed (at least for my computer), this is between the two methods suggested by angainor, and it has the advantage that you don't have to create a new variable if you prefer not to.